# SoftKinect ds325 (aka Creative Senz3D) and Raspberry Pi?

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi, kinect, intel-galileo

Is there a way to get a depth stream from ds325 on devices such as Raspberry pi?
What if to use Intel Galileo board instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a x86 or x64 board, you can use the softkinetic driver and sdk for linux right away.

Raspberry Pi is Arm architecture, can be done if you compile yourself.
http://www.hirotakaster.com/weblog/openni2-ds325-driver-for-android-and-arm-linuxraspberry-pi/